# SQL filetype commands not working in vim (filetype detected correctly)

Tags: sql, vim

There are various features fo the SQL filetype plugin mentioned [in this helpfile](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/vim/vim-48.1/runtime/doc/ft_sql.txt) that do not seem to work for me. I have installed the following files in to the correct places (all called sql.vim)

- syntax - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=498
- ftplugin - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=454

Was this even necessary? The syntax highlighting is now correct, but should something that is in the help files by default require downloading plugins?

Anyway, for example, the functions [[,]],[] and ][ do not work as described, and :SQLSetType is not a recognised command. Do I need to do more to enable these?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Vim already comes with SQL support so you don't have to download anything. Do you have `filetype plugin indent on` and `syntax on` in your vimrc?

Comment: Yep, it was filetype plugin indent. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL syntax and filetype plugins by David Fishburn are indeed distributed with the Vim runtime; you only need to install them into your `~/.vim/` directory if you want a newer version than what is delivered by your current Vim version. (So usually, no.)

If the syntax is working but the filetype definitions aren't, you're likely missing

```
:filetype plugin indent on
```

in your `~/.vimrc`. You can check the `:scriptnames` output and with `:verbose nmap ]]`.

Comment: okay, despite having the read the help page for filetype, I still thought that the indent was actually just setting indent guidance. Works perfectly now, thank you very much!